# How can I test for a systematic increase in Y as a function of X in data modeled by a sigmoid curve?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have a psychophysical dataset in which the contrast level (a continuous variable) is expected to influence the proportion of correct responses (correct response:  categorical [boolean]).  Traditionally, these kinds of data are modeled by a psychometric function (in effect, a sigmoid curve constrained to chance performance).  In my case, I'm using the following formula to fit my data:

```
1 / (1 + exp(-(x - theta) / sigma))
```

Additionally, this experiment was performed with a repeated-measures design, so there is a categorical `subject` column.

I would like to demonstrate that the proportion of correct responses increases as a function of contrast, bearing in mind that the design is not fully-factorial, i.e.:  the exact contrasts vary between subjects.

Is there some form of mixed-effect logistic regression I could (should?) use for such data?

I've done a linear mixed-effect model so far, but it seems hackish to apply a linear model when there's a strong *a priori* expectation that the data were produced by a sigmoidal function.  This concerns me even more since such a linear regression intercepts at around .3, which suggests that chance performance is at 30%; in reality, it should be at 50%, and a sigmoidal function estimates this correctly.  In other words, I'm concerned that linear mixed-effect models will muddy my interpretation and I'd much prefer some non-linear mixed-effect model.

I apologize if anything is unclear and I am happy to provide further details.  I'm not a statistician, so I ask that you please bear with me...

Comment: The question "is there some form of *mixed effects logistic regression*...?" may be answered by [typing those four keywords into the search bar](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mixed+effects+logistic+regression). Clearly the answer is yes and examples are easily found on site. You may want to ask a different question relating to the specifics of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mixed-effects logistic regression, with R synatx such a model could be

```
lme4::glmer( correct ~ x + (1 | Subject), family=binomial(link="log"), 
             data=your_data_frame, ... )
```

with a random intercept for each `Subject`, or if you want also random slopes

```
lme4::glmer( correct ~ x + (1 + x | Subject), family=binomial(link="log"), 
             data=your_data_frame, ... )
```